# On the edge of the swath and the reflection of the sun

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, satellite

In the Sentinel-2 image data, there is an overexposure near the water surface. I have examined several images and found that it is common to the eastern edge of the swath, so I think it is a reflection of the sun.

Is this phenomenon common to optical satellites? Also, do you think it affects the reflectivity?

An overhead image of Japan is included for reference.
**Reference**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try BRDF correction. It basically attempts to reduce those optical effects of different sun angles on the reflectance by normalizing everything.

See this [medium post](https://medium.com/sentinel-hub/looking-at-the-right-angle-easy-sentinel-2-brdf-correction-with-sentinel-hub-728f1dc61fe9) for more info. You can also interactively check the outcome of the processing in the new [Copernicus Browser](https://sentinelshare.page.link/VHjh). It's free, you just have to sign up.

Answer (score 0):

The physical name of this effect is [sunglint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunglint). This is the case for all satellites that have swaths large enough (typically S2 and S3).